# Multiply two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, e.g.

```
a = {1,2,3}

b = {4,5,6}
```

I'd like to multiply each element from the first list with each element from the second, like this:

```
{1*4, 2*4, 3*4, 1*5, 2*5, 3*5, 1*6, 2*6, 3*6}
```

I only need the result:

```
{4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18}
```

I have found a solution for this:

```
Drop[Flatten[Reap[For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, Sow[i*{4, 5, 6}]]]], 1]
```

However, I think this is overly complicated -- and number 12 is in there two times. Isn't there a much simpler way to do this? Multiply two lists?

Comment: `Union @@ Outer[Times, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to produce the result you seek is:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[i*j, {i, a}, {j, b}]]]
```

> {4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18}

This will also work, and generalizes easily to more than two lists:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[TensorProduct[a, b]]]
```

`TensorProduct` runs in time similar to `KronekerProduct` and `Outer`.

Answer (score 10):

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6};
Flatten[KroneckerProduct[a, b]]
```

> {4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18}

Use `DeleteDuplicates` to, well, delete duplicates.

Answer (score 10):

```
DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten @ Outer[Times, a, b]
```

> {4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18}

Also, shorter but much slower

```
DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples @ {a, b}]
```

> {4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18}

**Note:** If speed is a concern, then `Outer`, `KroneckerProduct`  and `TensorProduct` are much faster than `Table` and `Tuples` methods:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{a, b} = RandomInteger[100, {2, 1500}];
r1 = DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten @ Outer[Times, a, b]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0103

```
r2 = DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples @ {a, b}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.92

```
r3 = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[i*j, {i, a}, {j, b}]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.78

```
r4 = DeleteDuplicates @Flatten[KroneckerProduct[a, b]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.011

```
r5 = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[TensorProduct[a, b]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.011

```
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4 == r5
```

> True